# Python equivalent to clojure reductions

Tags: python

In Clojure, we have a function like this

```
(reductions str ["foo" "bar" "quax"])
=> ["foo" "foobar" "foobarquax"]
```

or

```
(reductions + [1 2 3 4 5])
=> [1 3 6 10 15]
```

It's basically just reduce but it collects the intermediate results.

I'm having trouble finding an equivalent in Python. Does a base library function exist.

Python 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```
from itertools import accumulate

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print([*accumulate(l)])
```

Prints:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of the * syntax, it's like splatting! :D

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.8 we can use `assignment expression :=`:

```
data = ["one", "two", "three"]

item = ""
print([item := item + v for v in data])
```

Comment: start item as the empty sum, in this case it would be the empty string. Makes it much clearer

Comment: I agree with you, it's better to simplify